# Foreach id in one table, insert row in another table

Tags: sql

I have two tables. Table 'locations' is One-To-Many/One related with table 'resources' with foreign key location_id. Something like this

```
locations -> id | location
resources -> id | location_id | name | value
```

I have a lot of records in 'locations'. Now i want to add for each existing 'locations.id' in 'locations', a record in 'resources' with default values for name and value and the location_id of course.

I tried query below which generates partially the desired result, because this sql query dosent set values for 'resoruces.name' and 'resources.value'. They should be respectively "standard" and "1".

```
INSERT INTO service_categories(location_id) SELECT id FROM locations;
```

I just cant construct the query with adding values for this fields. How to do this?
The result which i want is something like this:

```
    id | location_id | name     | value
-------------------------------------
    1  | 1           | Standard | 1
    2  | 2           | Standard | 1
    3  | 3           | Standard | 1
    4  | 4           | Standard | 1
    5  | 5           | Standard | 1
    6  | 6           | Standard | 1
    7  | 7           | Standard | 1
    8  | 8           | Standard | 1
....
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work, if the table `resources` doesn't already exist:

```
SELECT
    location_id as id,
    location_id,
    'Standard' as name,
    1 as value
INTO resources
FROM locations
```

If the table does already exist then you'd write this instead:

```
INSERT INTO resources (id, location_id, name, value)
SELECT
    location_id as id,
    location_id,
    'Standard' as name,
    1 as value
FROM locations
```

The string literal will vary based on which RDBMS you're using.  For instance, I believe MySQL uses backticks and not single quotes.

Comment: Thank you! With one addition to query it works perfectly! 

insert into resources (location_id, name, value) select id as location_id, "Standard" as name, 1 as value from locations where id not in (select location_id from resources)